# What is the best way to make a zoom-in effect on Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, zooming, flash-cs5

I have a world map and want to create a zoom-in effect.
Ideally, it would be able to have a "magnifying glass" looking cursor that when clicked, it would zoom in on that area of the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with four things:

X
Y
scaleX
scaleY

Oh, and mouse event listeners, of course.

Answer (score 0):

or you can play about with flash's inbuilt tween class:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
```